# SQL: 2 same vowels regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I need a regex for 2 same vowels in a varchar.

Like `'linEbrEak'` (but only 2 not more and not less)

I thought of something like:

```
'%[aeiouAEIOU]%[aeiouAEIOU]%'
```

But that gives me any 2 vowels. I want two of the same kind.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Is this even possible in Regex? Thanks very much!

More examples:

```
LeIpzIg
LOndOn
```

Edit: It is ok if it's not possible (too difficult maybe) in regex, I am happy with other solutions too, but they should be easy to read, fast and short.

Comment: for me looks like you want not Regex but use this with LIKE :)

Comment: Does it have to be a single regex?  It would be a lot cleaner with a replace followed by a regex.  If so what's the real-world usage?  Sounds like a bizzare requirement.

Comment: No this is not a real-world usage, but an exercise for a SQL Assignment... It's ok to not do it with regex but it should be clean and fast.

Comment: As I said I don't know if it's possible to do this in regex...

Comment: @Darka Could you give me an example please?

Comment: you can use '%[a]%[a]%' and so on. You will make several statements (maybe not good). I think @EricZ gave good example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't pretty or short but it is simple.

```
SELECT word
FROM tabl
WHERE
  -- assuming case sensitive based on your example
  (word LIKE '%[Aa]%[Aa]%' AND word NOT LIKE '%[Aa]%[Aa]%[Aa]%')
  OR
  (word LIKE '%[Ee]%[Ee]%' AND word NOT LIKE '%[Ee]%[Ee]%[Ee]%')
  OR
  (word LIKE '%[Ii]%[Ii]%' AND word NOT LIKE '%[Ii]%[Ii]%[Ii]%')
  OR
  (word LIKE '%[Oo]%[Oo]%' AND word NOT LIKE '%[Oo]%[Oo]%[Oo]%')
  OR
  (word LIKE '%[Uu]%[Uu]%' AND word NOT LIKE '%[Uu]%[Uu]%[Uu]%')
```

It occurs to me that you didn't specify what to do for a place that has two of one vowel and three of another. Does that qualify? If not (Say `Alaska StatE PEak Park` was bad even though it has exactly 2 E's in it) then you might want this instead:

```
SELECT word 
FROM tabl 
WHERE
  -- assuming case sensitive based on your example
  ( word LIKE '%[Aa]%[Aa]%'
    OR word LIKE '%[Ee]%[Ee]%'
    OR word LIKE '%[Ii]%[Ii]%'
    OR word LIKE '%[Oo]%[Oo]%'
    OR word LIKE '%[Uu]%[Uu]%' 
  )
  AND word NOT LIKE '%[Aa]%[Aa]%[Aa]%'
  AND word NOT LIKE '%[Ee]%[Ee]%[Ee]%'
  AND word NOT LIKE '%[Ii]%[Ii]%[Ii]%'
  AND word NOT LIKE '%[Oo]%[Oo]%[Oo]%'
  AND word NOT LIKE '%[Uu]%[Uu]%[Uu]%'
```

Comment: Also, to make the second solution a tiny bit more uniform, the NOT LIKE series could be rewritten as `... AND NOT (word LIKE '%[Aa]%[Aa]%[Aa]%' OR word LIKE ...)`. It won't gain anything else, though.

Comment: Thanks, it may be not the what I searched (regex) but it works!

Comment: Yeah, I only know MSSQL, MySQL, and PostgreSQL. Of the three, only PostgreSQL actually has "back references" that would allow this to be done fairly cleanly. `WHERE word ~ '([aeiou]).*\1' AND NOT word ~ '([aeiou]).*\1.*\1'` might work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution

```
DECLARE @txt VARCHAR(100) = 'LeIpzIg'

DECLARE @vowels TABLE ( letter CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @vowels VALUES ('a'),('e'),('i'),('o'),('u') 

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT letter , LEN(@txt) - LEN(REPLACE(LOWER(@txt),letter,'')) as number_of_vowel
    FROM @vowels
    WHERE LOWER(@txt) LIKE '%'+ letter +'%'
) 
SELECT letter
FROM cte 
WHERE number_of_vowel >= 2
```